# How exactly can I migrate to a new EFI boot partition?

Tags: boot, uefi

Of the existing questions, [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111845/how-to-move-efi-and-boot-partitions) looks most similar to what I'm doing, only that I try to grow my partition and I'm lost as to why there is different partitions mounted to /boot/ and /boot/efi and how to proceed without shooting my feet.

So far I created a new partition, mounted it to `/newBoot` and did `sudo rsync -a /boot/ /newBoot/`, so I assume I have all the relevant files in the new partition to switch.

```
$ lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid
NAME                        FSTYPE   SIZE FSUSED LABEL   PARTLABEL          MOUNTPOINT UUID                                   PARTUUID
sda                                  7.3T                                                                                     
└─sda1                      crypto   7.3T                                              4dffc196-9926-43d9-a7c8-38898681f402   85b3a656-4886-4b37-b9c1-2acb0158587a
...
nvme0n1                            931.5G                                                                                     
├─nvme0n1p1                 vfat     512M   5.3M         EFI System Partition
│                                                                           /boot/efi  FD0E-EECA                              587cf214-f068-4879-a833-9dffa5ec6e3d
├─nvme0n1p2                 ext2     488M 313.7M                            /boot      606a1976-d1c2-4246-a256-a8afddb04f84   2e10e277-560f-4f5e-abce-1dce5187a7f0
...
└─nvme0n1p4                 vfat     1.5G        NEWBOOT newboot                       530D-4828                              ea886018-714f-46fb-8f21-785c74543891
$ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0004
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,587cf214-f068-4879-a833-9dffa5ec6e3d,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
$ sudo efibootmgr -c -L ubuntuNew -l \\EFI\\UBUNTU\\SHIMX64.EFI
$ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0004
Boot0000* ubuntuNew HD(1,GPT,85b3a656-4886-4b37-b9c1-2acb0158587a,0xffff,0x3a3535ca9)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,587cf214-f068-4879-a833-9dffa5ec6e3d,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
```

so while I don't understand why there are two partitions involved in the current `/boot` folder, I think one should work, too? At least so reads the linked above questions's selected answer, right?

Now what's missing? `/etc/fstab`?

```
$ cat /etc/fstab 
...
UUID=606a1976-d1c2-4246-a256-a8afddb04f84 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
...
UUID=FD0E-EECA  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
...
```

Now according to `lsblk` and `efibootmgr -v` (thanks @oldfred) the new, first boot option would want to use `sda1` and not `nvme0n1p4`. `sda1` is an external drive I certainly do not want to boot from. Why did it default to that??

- What change is missing so it boots from the new partition?
- Do I have to change the `UUID` of `/boot` in fstab prior to reboot?
- Do I need a separate partition for `/boot/efi`?

Comment: UEFI uses GUID/partUUID. To see partUUID. `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid`  The UUID in fstab should be the UUID of the ESP partition you are using. Often best to do a new grub install and use efibootmgr to remove old entries in ESP. see `man efibootmgr` and -b xxx -B options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having both `/boot` and `/boot/efi` as separate filesystems is overkill, but:

- very old BIOS-based systems might need a separate `/boot` partition to avoid BIOS limitations
- any systems booting in UEFI style will need `/boot/efi` or equivalent ESP partition, because that is what the firmware expects to find the bootloader file in.
- having a separate unencrypted `/boot` will allow the use of any encryption method supported by `cryptsetup` on the root filesystem, instead of the more limited set of encryptions understood by GRUB.

The default partitioning of a modern Debian/Ubuntu has both as separate partitions, so the default configuration can cover the widest possible range of systems.

As mentioned in the comments by oldfred, UEFI identifies the ESP partition to use by a partition-unique GUID in the GPT partition table. That GUID is known as PARTUUID in Linux. `lsblk -o +partuuid` will display it.

Your `efibootmgr` command was almost correct. To create the ubuntuNew boot option using the correct disk, you should have used:

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/nvme0n1 -L ubuntuNew -l \\EFI\\UBUNTU\\SHIMX64.EFI
```

`efibootmgr` will look up the PARTUUID on its own and automatically use it to create the new boot entry. You'll only need to specify the disk (unless the disk has multiple EFI System Partitions on it).

Once `shimx64.efi` has loaded `grubx64.efi`, on systems configured Debian/Ubuntu-style, it will read `grub.cfg` in the same directory as `grubx64.efi`. That file contains just a few lines identifying the filesystem UUID of the filesystem that contains the `/boot` directory (whether it is a separate partition or just a regular directory on the root filesystem). As a result, Debian/Ubuntu systems can *always* have the "main" GRUB configuration file at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, no matter if the system uses BIOS or UEFI. If you have a large number of systems of different ages, it's convenient.

For reference, RedHat 7 and 8 have the actual GRUB configuration at `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` on BIOS-style systems, and at `/boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg` on UEFI systems.

**However**, if you want to merge `/boot` and `/boot/efi`, there are few things to note:

- The bootloader path given to `efibootmgr` is based on the root of the ESP filesystem. Originally that path starts at `/boot/efi`, so `\\EFI\\UBUNTU\\SHIMX64.EFI` refers to `/boot/efi/EFI/UBUNTU/SHIMX64.EFI` as viewed from Linux. If you use just `/boot`, then you'll need to either move the UBUNTU directory up one level, ot specify the bootloader path as `\\EFI\\EFI\\UBUNTU\\SHIMX64.EFI`.
- `/boot` needs to be something that is understood by GRUB, so that it can load the kernel and initramfs files from there. Ubuntu's UEFI version of GRUB will definitely understand ext2 and vfat; so if you merge `/boot` and `/boot/efi` into a single vfat partition, GRUB will have no problems. You can't use ext2 because the firmware will need to read SHIMX64.EFI and GRUBX64.EFI from that partition, and the typical UEFI firmware won't be able to understand ext2.
- At boot time, `/boot` is only needed by GRUB, not by the Linux kernel: you could leave `/boot` unmounted and the system would still boot just fine. But you'll want to keep `/boot` mounted so that kernel updates can happen normally. (Or if you really wanted to hide it by leaving it unmounted, then you could add scripts to `/etc/kernel/pre*.d/` to automatically mount it before kernel updates are installed, and to `/etc/kernel/post*.d` to unmount it again after the installation/removal of a particular kernel package is done.)

Bootloader is often perceived as a "scary and dangerous" if you don't have a firm grasp of what the requirements are. On the other hand, it's usually rather self-contained, so problems related to just the bootloader are usually not that difficult to fix... once you get past the first hurdle of booting the system from an external media, so you can start fixing it. I would not say that a system with a non-functional bootloader is "toast": it just needs a little external help.

Comment: So the system partition being encrypted calls for an extra partition for `/boot/efi`? If I have the old boot on `/dev/nvme0n1`, too, I probably have to be more specific with `efibootmgr`?

Comment: `sudo efibootmgr --create --disk /dev/nvme0n1 --part 4 --label ubuntuNewer --loader \\EFI\\UBUNTU\\SHIMX64.EFI` appears to be the right command. `efibootmgr -v` now looks good. Only scared to see if it will boot or not.

Comment: When booting UEFI-style, the ESP partition is always required because the firmware expects to find a FAT32 partition that contains the bootloader in the form of an `*.efi` file. Different Linux distributions may mount it as `/boot/efi`, or `/boot`, or even leave it completely unmounted except while actually updating the bootloader or its configuration, but the existence of an ESP partition **is a firmware requirement** when booting UEFI-style. Your `efibootmgr` command looks good.

Comment: @telcoM.  EFI firmware is required by the UEFI specification (see section 13.3.1.1) to support EFI System Partitions formatted as FAT12, FAT16 or FAT32 - not just FAT32.

Comment: So if I reboot now, my system is toast? I have to re-do the `/newboot` partition but instead of `fat32` as `ext2` and not copy all the content of `/boot`, omitting the `/boot/efi` part and mount the old `efi` partition to `/newboot/efi`? I read the answer as saying that `/boot` and its `/boot/efi` may all be on the same `fat32` partition?

Comment: @fpmurphy Yes, the current versions of the specification allow all three forms of FAT filesystems, but UEFI specification 2.3.1 used to restrict FAT12 and FAT16 to removable media only, and FAT32 was the primary requirement. So to assure maximum compatibility for even old UEFI versions, FAT32 is the type to use. Of course, implementations are free to go above and beyond specification: Apple UEFI can also read HFS+, and at least some Asus UEFI implementations also understand (some versions of) NTFS.

Comment: Now if I tell the system to boot from the old efi partition, how does it know to use the new boot partition? I think I would be back to square one.

Comment: So now what's missing is to put the new root's UUID into `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`? I'm confused about it being shorter than the old UUID (it doesn't look like a UUID). `530D-4828`.

Comment: FAT32 and older FAT filesystems don't support real UUIDs, so they use the volume serial number instead, and that is why you're seeing the shorter ID.

Comment: @telcoM I intend to accept your answer as it was what got me where I am and contains more general information. I have still not yet rebooted. Please check my answer if it makes sense. I think I don't need to touch `efibootmgr` at all.

Comment: I accepted your answer but in my case, messing around with the efi partition would have complicated things, so I resolved with my solution below. Successfully rebooted after shooting my foot ending up in a grub shell but that was because I didn't execute my solution precisely 

Answer (score 1):

The boot loader will look for what you currently have mounted to `/boot/efi`, so if you don't want to also grow that partition, you can keep that partition as is and just make one tiny change to a file as described below.

## Preparing the new boot partition

1. Create a new `ext2` partition with the desired size. This partition doesn't need a boot flag - your efi partition is the entry point and will delegate to this new partition.
2. Mount the new partition somewhere. `/newBoot` for example
3. Copy over your files from the old boot partition, for example using `rsync --recursive --delete --archive /boot/ /newBoot/`
4. Delete the content of `/newBoot/efi/`, here that was just one folder: `rm -rf /newBoot/efi/EFI/`. Do not delete `newBoot/efi/`. We want to mount the old `efi` folder there.

## Tell `efi` to use the new partition

Figure out `/newBoot`'s UUID:

```
$ lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid
NAME                                          FSTYPE        SIZE FSUSED LABEL     PARTLABEL            MOUNTPOINT           UUID                                   PARTUUID
nvme0n1                                                   931.5G                                                                                                   
├─nvme0n1p1                                   vfat          512M   5.3M           EFI System Partition /boot/efi            FD0E-EECA                              587cf214-f068-4879-a833-9dffa5ec6e3d
├─nvme0n1p2                                   ext2          488M 313.7M                                /boot                606a1976-d1c2-4246-a256-a8afddb04f84   2e10e277-560f-4f5e-abce-1dce5187a7f0
├─nvme0n1p3                                   crypto_LUKS 927.7G                                                            e7f674b8-4bec-4502-a1e5-0e93aa34786f   2fed2ecb-b548-479b-aa3f-7f1bbfb9981f
│ └─sda3_crypt                                LVM2_member 927.7G                                                            9tx8Yv-XDCR-RmGf-fmXo-WiX2-SDpG-xH1si4 
│   ├─ubuntu--gnome--vg-root                  ext4        911.6G 734.2G                                /                    1cccfb0a-69da-4246-a071-52f882681418   
│   └─ubuntu--gnome--vg-swap_1                swap         15.8G                                       [SWAP]               e3facfb8-db2e-426d-aef4-b6c81004fd6f   
└─nvme0n1p4                                   ext2          1.5G        newBoot   newBoot                                   5aca79e7-b740-46d3-bc76-aa7e8b8b93da   9e8baf2f-2118-4042-9c47-7ffb824ada52
```

Edit `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` accordingly, replacing the old current UUID with the new one:

```
# cat /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
# search.fs_uuid 606a1976-d1c2-4246-a256-a8afddb04f84 root 
search.fs_uuid 5aca79e7-b740-46d3-bc76-aa7e8b8b93da root 
set prefix=($root)'/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

## Finishing up

Now the system should already boot from the new partition but `/boot/` would be the old after booting from the new. Edit `/etc/fstab` so that system updates find all files in their place:

```
# UUID=606a1976-d1c2-4246-a256-a8afddb04f84 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
UUID=5aca79e7-b740-46d3-bc76-aa7e8b8b93da /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
```

The `/boot/efi` line in `/etc/fstab` remains as it was:

```
UUID=FD0E-EECA  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
```